# How I can report the presence of a bad character on all the data of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

On my dataframe :

[image]

what is the easiest way to browse the datas of my dataframe which are numbers and detect characters of type: ', "and report them ?
Can we avoid the series?

I want to browse my dataframe and detect the single quote and double quote present in the values ​​and if there are any I just want to display a logging.error with the presence of the character on a specific row.

Example 1 : `"Double quote are detected on R3 and R1"`

Example 2 : `"Simple quote are detected on R2"`

Comment: What do you mean by "*report*"?

Comment: @U12-Forward  prevent with an error message the presence of bad characters on a specific data. Exemple : " is present on R1 or double quote are present on R3

Comment: Check my answer :)

Comment: @U12-Forward i have : "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found"  Sorry I updated a new dataframe I'm working on

Comment: Ah! edited my answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
print('Single quote are detected on row(s): ', df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains("'")).any(axis=1)[lambda x: x].index.tolist())


print('Double quote are detected on row(s): ', df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains('"')).any(axis=1)[lambda x: x].index.tolist())
```

**Output:**

```
Single quote are detected on row(s):  ['R2']

Double quote are detected on row(s):  ['R1', 'R3']
```

Comment: Hello, i have a error message : AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @meuhfunk  Use my edited version above.  with `.astype(str)` in the code

Comment: @meuhfunk  Does it work ?   Seen you mentioned it works in the comment and later on removed the comment.   Any issue ?

Comment: it work but "0" not detected on R3 however 0" on R1 is detected ! @SeanBean

Comment: @meuhfunk  Let me take a look.  I run the codes above based on your sample data and got R3 detected also.

Comment: @meuhfunk  Would the  double quotes in "0" in R3 be some **funny double quotes characters** ?

Comment: @meuhfunk  That's great!   Please accept the answer if no other issue.  I'll continue supporting you if any further issue.  No worry.

Comment: @seanBean : yes

Answer (score 0):

Try `assert`:

```
x = ''.join(df.astype(str).agg(''.join))
assert not ((':' in x) or ('"' in x)), "Bad characters on a data"
```

Comment: i have : "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found" Sorry I updated a new dataframe I'm working on

Comment: @meuhfunk I already edited my answer

Comment: I have assert not (("'" in x) or ('"' in x))
AssertionError

Comment: I still have the message: AssertionError: Bad characters on a data

Comment: @meuhfunk Isn't that what you want?

Comment: In fact I want to browse my dataframe and detect the single quote and double quote present in the values ​​and if there are any I just want to display a logging.error with the presence of the character on a specific row. Example 1 : "Double quote are detected on R3 and R1"  Example 2 : Simple quote are detected on R2

Comment: @SeaBean Yeah! It's really hard to answer questions and have positive feedback anymore! :P